# Picasso image inside a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager with cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, cardview

I'm trying to parse json data which has image and text of a DashboardActivityNew to recyclerView, I'm getting the only problem images from json. I am using Picasso.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
ProgressBar progressBarnewdash;
CustomAdapterDashboard adapterDashboard;
String url5 = "http://support.deverp.com/dms/dms_menu.aspx";
List<DataModelNew> list; 

private static final String TAG = DashboardActivityNew.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_new);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvdashboad);
    progressBarnewdash = findViewById(R.id.pbnew1);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(DashboardActivityNew.this, 3);

    loaddata();
    adapterDashboard = new CustomAdapterDashboard(DashboardActivityNew.this, list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterDashboard);
    adapterDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

**This is json call**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("menu");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    DataModelNew dataModelNew = new DataModelNew();
                                    JSONObject count = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Log.e("count", count.getString("menuimage"));


                                    dataModelNew.setMenuhead(count.getString("menuhead"));
                                    dataModelNew.setMenuimage(count.getString("menuimage"));
                                    dataModelNew.setMenutitle(count.getString("menutitle"));
                                    list.add(dataModelNew);
                                    adapterDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**This is my view holder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    myViewHolder.textView1title.setText(list.get(i).getMenutitle());

    Log.e("imageholder>>>", list.get(i).getMenuimage() + "");

    Picasso.get().load(list.get(i).getMenuimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.erp).fit().into(myViewHolder.imageViewurl, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e("success>>>", list.get(i).getMenuimage() + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e("error>>>", list.get(i).getMenuimage()+e+ "");
        }
    });
```

**This is itemview**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView1title, textViewhead;
    ImageView imageViewurl;
    CardView cardViewdash;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();

        textView1title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdash);

        textViewhead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        cardViewdash = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardnew);
        imageViewurl = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivdash);
```

**This is logcat**

I am getting the images both set and get but no loading images and loading images but no display images in my dashboard.

[image: 1]

**This is my items layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardnew"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_85sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_76sdp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_dashboard"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivdash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorwhite"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/erp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvdash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Quatation Report"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Please make sure that your image urls are valid.

Comment: you have check logcat image they have all image set and get ...but i am not understand image display disappears even when the images are set and then gone.?

Comment: [http://support.deverp.com/FileUpload/1/APP CONFIG/180221147/attendance.png]

hit the above url on your browser and check it's valid or not, please.

Comment: Specifically your url contains space which invalidate the url, most probably. Please check that out.

Comment: No sir, this is sample url image http://support.deverp.com/FileUpload/1/APP_CONFIG/180221147/attreport.png and check .this is validate url and my problem is that they have all images set and get and then automatically to load disappears..? this is main probelm my question

Comment: Now, check if the bitmap is null or not

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myViewHolder.imageViewurl.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    if(bitmap!=null){
                        myViewHolder.imageViewurl.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }else{
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: null");
                    }

Comment: Ok,so how to solve this solution.

Comment: is it null?? if not, then setImageBitmap should resolve your problem.

Comment: i have apply your code but i am getting error so please solution only for picasso.

Comment: Try detaching your adapter from recycleview and reattaching it.

Comment: Got your solution?

Comment: No sir ,same problem

Comment: solve my problem, only this line remove  android:background="@color/colorwhite" and solve my problem.